# Was "leather" really a technology introduced by Europeans to the Plains Indians?

Tags: technology, native-americans

I was watching a university lecture about the Comanche called "[Nomads in the Tribal Zone: Conflict and Compromise in 18th Century New Mexico](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJHnYuILkts)". The lecturer said that leather was one of the technologies the Comanche acquired from French. I'm wondering if maybe the lecturer misspoke? I re-winded, it is clearly her words. Her point was the Comanche were resourceful, finding new uses for various technologies brought by European traders, but I think leather is just animal skins that have been treated, so how would that have been new to the Comanche?

Comment: "Leather" is a substance, not a technology.  Can you be more specific about the technology that she asserted was introduced?  Perhaps it was some better tanning process?  It would also be useful to know if it was just the Comanche who were previously ignorant of the technique.

Comment: It didn't say, just that the Comanche had gotten three things from the French: steel, horses, and leather. They Comanche used the leather for making horse's armor and small shields. Not sure why leather was one introduced, so I wonder if she just made a mistake in her words in the presentation.

Comment: I'm guessing this is reference to methods other than [brain tanning](https://www.leather-dictionary.com/index.php/Brain_tanning).

Comment: Yeah, more typically people say Comanche receive steel, horses, and *guns* from the Europeans by trading hides.

Comment: they probably had knowledge of making leather, but lacked the technology to do so in bulk. That might be where the confusion originates?

Comment: @Village can you fully cite your source lecture (link if available online). If the lecturer has published, perhaps we can find sources linked in those publications.

Comment: [The process of brain tanning is explained by an Ojibwa elder.](https://www.native-art-in-canada.com/braintanning.html) is an interesting read about how hides are traditionally treated.  Unfortunately there's nothing to indicate how old these practices are.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps it depends on your precise definition of leather.

Since way back in Palaeolithic times, hunters had made used of the skins of the animals they killed for clothing and for shelters. They had learned to scrape off the inner layer with fat attached, and the outer layer with hair attached. To prevent the skin from decaying it could be sun-dried to give rawhide, or cured either with smoke or by rubbing with fats or oils. At this point it could be called leather, and according to its origin and treatment it could vary from hard and stiff to soft and supple. It was used for clothes, footwear, gloves, tents, buckets and many other things – even sails could be made of leather. It was a stronger alternative to cloth.

I suspect that this was as far as the Native Americans got. Europeans however were accustomed to using chemicals.

At some point it was discovered that soaking the skin in alum would give a soft, white leather, although it was not water-resistant. The major breakthrough came some time around the 5th century BC in the Roman Empire, when the tanning of leather was discovered. This involves soaking the leather in a solution of tannin, obtained from tree bark. It is an industrial process, requiring many different tubs of various strengths of tannin solution. The leather is gradually moved from one tub to another, successively increasing the solution strength, for a period of over a year. The tubs were usually placed well away from the town, as the smell was objectionable. The tannins combined permanently with the collagen in the skin to produce a leather that was waterproof, chemically stable and which would not decay. It was superior in quality to cured leather, although cured leather continued to be produced as it was easier to do. Sometimes a shoe would be made with a sole of tanned leather but an upper of cured leather.

The reference for the above is an article "Tanning and Leather" by Carol van Driel-Murray, in the book The Oxford Handbook of Engineering and Technology in the Classical World

As an aside, the leather tanneries using these traditional methods are one of the tourist sights of Fez in Morocco. You can see the skins moving from one vat to another with a stronger solution.